# Datepicker не работает dateformat

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Если выбрать 05.05.2021 в первом datepicker, то второй выбор даты не должен выбирать ничего до 05.05.2021.
Скрипт работает с форматом yy-mm-dd с форматом dd.mm.yy не хочет. Как исправить?

```
<script>
    $("#start").datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
     
        minDate: new Date(),
        maxDate: '+2y',
        onSelect: function(date){
     
            var selectedDate = new Date(date);
            var msecsInADay = 86400000;
            var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay);
     
            $("#end").datepicker( "option", "minDate", endDate );
            $("#end").datepicker( "option", "maxDate", '+2y' );
     
        }
    });
     
    $("#end").datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
     
    });
    </script>
```